# Somehow a class variable is set to a changed value from previous multiprocessing call when using multiprocessing.map

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

This shouldn't be possible.  (I add simply checking processing time.) The main process shows the value to be unchanged.  Running multiprocessing.start gets the original value, but somehow the subprocess value gets the updated value from a previous call.

Here is the output:

```
multiprocessing start
printOne  1
printOne  1
tuple + tuple size 62500 62500
printOne  1
tuple + tuple size 62500 62500
printOne  1
tuple + tuple size 62500 62500
printOne  1
tuple + tuple size 62500 62500
printOne  1
multiprocessing time (raw):  847.4807
multiprocessing time:  878.7786
single threaded start
printOne  1
printOne  1
tuple + tuple size 1000000 1000000
printOne  1
single threaded time:  31.7371
map a+a start
printOne  1
printOne  2 printself  1
int self + int self size... 1
printOne  2 printself  1
int self + int self size... 1
printOne  2 printself  1
```

printOne is somehow set to set to 2, when it is seen as 1 in the main process.  printOne is back to one in the main process.

The code doing this (func is addtogether.add):

```
        print('multiprocessing start')
        print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne)
        values1 = [data1[i:i + poolsize] for i in range(0, len(data1), poolsize)]
        values2 = [data2[i:i + poolsize] for i in range(0, len(data2), poolsize)]

        time2 = time_ns()
        manager = Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()
        jobs = []
        for i in range(len(values1)):
            p = Process(target=compos.worker, args=(i, func, values1[i], values2[i], return_dict))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
            
        for proc in jobs:
            proc.join()
        
        print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne)
        print('multiprocessing time (raw): ', (time_ns() - time2)/1000000)

        print('single threaded start')
        print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne)
        time4 = time_ns()
        results4 = func(data1, data2)
        time5 = time_ns()
        print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne)
        print('single threaded time: ', (time5 - time4)/1000000)
        
        time5 = time_ns()
        print('map a+a start')
        print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne)
        results5 = pool.map(addtogether.doubleSelf, data1)
        print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne)
```

addtogether:

```
class addtogether(queryable.queryable):
    """add values"""
    
    printOne = 1
    printSelf = 1
    
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__() 
        self.a = a
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        """Add method"""
        if (isinstance(other.a, tuple) == True):

            **print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne)**
            print('tuple + tuple size', len(self.a), len(other.a))
            return tuple(map(lambda x, y : x + y, self.a, other.a))
                    
        if (addtogether.printOne < 2):
            print('int + int size...', 1, 1)
            addtogether.printOne = addtogether.printOne + 1
            
        return self.a + other.a

    def doubleSelf(self):
        if (isinstance(self.a, int)):
            if (addtogether.printSelf < 2):
                **print('printOne ', addtogether.printOne, 'printself ', addtogether.printSelf)
**                print('int self + int self size...', 1)
                addtogether.printSelf = addtogether.printSelf + 1
                
            return self.a + self.a

        print('tuple self + tuple self size...', len(self.a))
        return tuple(map(lambda x, y : x + y, self.a, self.a))
```

I was expecting printOne is be set as 1 in each process, like what happened in the multiprocessing.start case.  Somehow it is set to 2 when doubleSelf is called for the first time.

Simplifying the case to call map twice in a row keeps print_one as 1 in  each subprocess.  Viewing print_one class attribute in the main process shows as 1.  Running map immediately afterward has print_one as 2 (as each subprocess set in the first call), as can be seen by the missing "int self + ..." print statement:

```
map a+a start
print_one  1
int self + int self size... 1 [ 1 ]
int self + int self size... 1 [ 1 ]
map a+a time:  240.666
map a+a start
print_one  1
map a+a time:  204.0005
```

Code:

```
        print('map a+a start')
        addtogether.print_one = 1
        print('print_one ', addtogether.print_one)
        results5 = pool.map(addtogether.doubleSelf, data1)
        #print('print_one ', addtogether.print_one)
        print('map a+a time: ', (time_ns() - time5)/1000000)

        time5 = time_ns()
        print('map a+a start')
        print('print_one ', addtogether.print_one)
        results5 = pool.map(addtogether.doubleSelf, data1)
        #print('print_one ', addtogether.print_one)
        print('map a+a time: ', (time_ns() - time5)/1000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use class attributes for this. Changing a class attribute value changes that value for every other process that access that class after the module is first instantiated. Change this to an instance attribute.

```py
class addtogether(queryable.queryable):  # Should be AddTogether
    """add values"""
    
    def __init__(self, a, printOne: int = 1, printSelf: int = 1):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.printOne = printOne  # Should be `print_one`
        self.printSelf = printSelf  # Should be `print_self`
```

**Note:** Your naming conventions do not follow PEP8 guidelines. Do other developers a favor and follow those guidelines.

Comment: Thanks.  I presumed there is only a single instance of a class in the main process.  The printOne value showed as 1 before the map function is called.  It immediately showed as 2 in the call to doubleSelf. and then as 1 after the exit.  In addtogether.__add__ it showed as 1.  The starmap and map functions create a new addtogether object for each element processed, so the instance variable print_one would be reinited each time, causing int self + int self size line to be printed a million times.  The class variable was supposed to get around this.  It was surprising start was ok, and map not.

Comment: Simply moving the multiprocessing.map function call to be before the process.start call, eliminates the class attribute issue.  So even though the attribute prints out as 1 in the main process, somehow the using the start function before using map causes the class attribute to be 2 (inc'ed in the int case).

Comment: One final note.  Running map the first time causes the class attribute to be inited to 1 for each process.  Running it immediately afterward with the same code, does not init the class attribute for the subprocesses.  It is set to 2.  In the main process it displays as 1.  So it seems the second call to map does not get a clean class (or even what is visible in the main thread.

Comment: As to speed of multithreading, doing 50 million adds vs 1 million makes a difference.  Single threaded is still faster (even for 400 million) but much closer to multithreaded version.  The lambda function for adding huge tuples is very efficient.

Comment: Most of the time in the multithreading case is serializing the data, so the trade off is calc complexity vs data set size.